# How to transfer data to parent template without code duplication,

Tags: laravel

I have main layout which contains a header, nav, footer and ofc many blade templates with 
inherited from him. My problem: i have categories which i need to connect in my navbar, also in many children templates, maybe it can be done somehow globally without duplication code.

It's my 'HomeContoller' return index template, but if i return my categories with `$categories` my main layout can't see this variable

```
public function index()
{  
    $posts = Post::paginate(10);

    $popularPosts = Post::orderByViews()->take(6)->get();

    return view('front.index', ['posts' => $posts, 'popularPosts' => $popularPosts]);
}
```

Now i return to layout.blade my `$categories` by this method.

```
@php
    $categories = App\Category::all();
@endphp
```

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case I would suggest the [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers) - especially, if you scroll a bit down on that page you'll see `Attaching A Composer To Multiple Views` - you could use:

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    $view->with('categories', App\Category::all());
});
```

You can register it under any of the existing providers for instance `AppServiceProvider` under the `boot` method:

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        View::composer('*', function ($view) {
            $view->with('categories', App\Category::all());
        });
    }
}
```